# How to combine UVs?

Tags: uv

I have finished unwrapping my mesh and have everything laid out in the UV editor. My mesh is identical on both sides so I'm trying to see if there's a way I can combine the identical UVs by 'laying them on top of' one another or something. I recall seeing a video where the person did this, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 0):

Delete one side of the mesh then add a **Mirror modifier** to recreate the deleted geometry.

Apply the modifier and you will find the UV islands of one side stacked perfectly above the UV islands of the other side.